# Creating a tar stream in memory from multiple file byte streams

Tags: python, amazon-s3, tar, tarfile

I'm trying to create a tar stream in memory add files to it and then save it to S3. But there is some issue and the files inside the ta have zero size. Can any one please advise? Code snippet below-

```
def tar_and_upload(bucket, keys, dest_bucket):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    file_obj = io.BytesIO()
    tar_file_obj = tarfile.open(mode = "w:gz", fileobj=file_obj)    
    response = {}
    for key in keys:
        obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        _bytes = obj["Body"].read()
        _file_name = key.split("/")[-1]
        tar_file_obj.addfile(tarfile.TarInfo(_file_name), _bytes)
    tar_file_obj.close()
    try:
        obj_name = "{}.tar.gz".format(str(uuid.uuid4()))
        s3.put_object(Body=file_obj.getvalue(), Bucket=dest_bucket, Key=obj_name)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Can't save tar to S3", exc_info=True)
        return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay apparently when adding byte streams to a tar, we need to explicitly specify the size.
Sample code-

```
import tarfile
import uuid
import io
import os

def tar_and_upload():
    file_obj = io.BytesIO()
    tar_file_obj = tarfile.open(mode = "w:gz", fileobj=file_obj)
    for filename in os.listdir("images"):
      print(filename)
      file_path = os.path.join("images", filename)
      #tar_file_obj.add(file_path)
      with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        _bytes = f.read()
        tar_info = tarfile.TarInfo(filename)
        tar_info.size = len(_bytes)
        tar_file_obj.addfile(tar_info, io.BytesIO(_bytes))
    tar_file_obj.close()
    try:
        obj_name = "{}.tar.gz".format(str(uuid.uuid4()))
        object_path = os.path.join("temp", obj_name)
        with open(object_path, "wb") as f:
          f.write(file_obj.getvalue())
        print(obj_name)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tar_and_upload()
```

Comment: Does this not store the entirety of the file data in the tar in memory before it is written/streamed? If not can you explain why not? From my reading of this it looks like the entire tar is in memory when .getvalue() is called

Answer (score 1):

```py
def tar_and_upload(bucket, keys, dest_bucket):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    file_obj = io.BytesIO()
    tar_file_obj = tarfile.open(mode = "w:gz", fileobj=file_obj)    
    response = {}
    for key in keys:
        obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        _bytes = obj["Body"].read()
        _file_name = key.split("/")[-1]
        info = tarfile.TarInfo(_file_name)
        info.size = obj["ContentLength"]
        info.mtime = s3.head_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)['LastModified'].timestamp()
        tar_file_obj.addfile(info, io.BytesIO(_bytes))
    tar_file_obj.close()
    try:
        obj_name = "{}.tar.gz".format(str(uuid.uuid4()))
        s3.put_object(Body=file_obj.getvalue(), Bucket=dest_bucket, Key=obj_name)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Can't save tar to S3", exc_info=True)
        return
```

For others, looking to do the same for s3 object

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Does this not store the entirety of the file data in the tar in memory before it is written/streamed to s3? If not can you explain why not? From my reading of this it looks like the entire tar is in memory when .getvalue() is called